Creating a custom Qcompleter in pyqt5
I want to create a custom qcompleter in pyqt5 to suggest some saved words and suggest again whenever '+' is typed.
    def setup_completer(self, input_field):
        """Set up QCompleter for the Diagnostique input field with an empty model initially."""
        empty_model = QStringListModel()  # Start with an empty model

        completer = QCompleter(empty_model)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchStartsWith)

        input_field.setCompleter(completer)

        # Connect textChanged signal to handle autocomplete suggestions
        input_field.textChanged.connect(
            lambda text: self.handle_text_changed(text=text, completer=completer)
        )

    def handle_text_changed(self, text, completer):
        """Handle text changes and update the popup with suggestions that match the input text."""
        # Extract the relevant part of the input text
        prefix = text.split("+")[-1].strip()

        # Load suggestions from the database
        suggestions = self.load_suggestions_from_db()

        # Filter matching suggestions
        matching_suggestions = [
            suggestion for suggestion in suggestions if suggestion.startswith(prefix)
        ]

        # Update the completer's model with matching suggestions
        model = completer.model()
        if isinstance(model, QStringListModel):
            model.setStringList(matching_suggestions)

        # Debug prints
        print("Prefix extracted:", prefix)
        print("Matching suggestions:", matching_suggestions)

I tried to add the list using setStringList but nothing appeared in the popup.
